# Trigonometric manipulation for $\arctan$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am trying to simplify $p = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{\pi}\arctan(\frac{V_b-V_a}{V_b+V_a}) \text{  to } p = \frac{2}{\pi}\arctan(\frac{V_b}{V_a})$.

I am having trouble starting as I can't see the relevant trigonometric manipulations to use on $arctan$ here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It follows from the formula for $\tan(x-y)$ that 
$$\arctan\frac{A-B}{1+AB}=\arctan(A)-\arctan(B).$$
Apply this with $A=\dfrac{V_b}{V_a}$ and $B=1$:
$$\frac{\frac{V_b}{V_a}-1}{1+\frac{V_b}{V_a}}=\frac{V_b-V_a}{V_a+V_b}$$
and thus,
$$\arctan\frac{V_b-V_a}{V_b+V_a}=\arctan(V_b/V_a)-\arctan(1)=\arctan(V_b/V_a)-\frac{\pi}{4}\,.$$

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do you have any reference (books or links) where I can brush up on these more advanced trig identities?

Comment: Advanced Trigonometry by Durell and Robson is good and has lots of exercises, but is quite old. Most identities involving the inverse trig functions can be derived directly from the addition and subtraction formulae.

Answer (score 2):

Note

$\arctan\frac{V_b-V_a}{V_b+V_a}= \arctan\frac{\frac{V_b}{V_a}-1}{1+1\cdot\frac{V_b}{V_a}}= \arctan \frac{V_b}{V_a} - \arctan1=
\arctan \frac{V_b}{V_a}-\frac\pi4
$

Thus,

$p = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{2}{\pi}\arctan\frac{V_b-V_a}{V_b+V_a}= \frac{2}{\pi}\arctan\frac{V_b}{V_a}$